# Page Titles - Including gender of a fashion product in page titles?

Tags: seo

I need a bit of help to decide whether it is worth including gender in page titles.

In the webmaster tools: I looked at our search queries that include "women", and they account for 9% of our total search queries for the site.
I am wondering if it is the right way assess the benefit of including "woman" or "men" in page titles, looking at it with existing results pointing to us already?
Is there another tool that I can check the actual queries that may not include us in search results?
Like google insights maybe? http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=shoes%2Cshoes%20for%20women&cmpt=q

So it looks like 1.1% of searches for "shoes" are also "shoes for women" is that correct?
As a direct comparison, doing the same analysis on our own search queries, I get 1.8% when comparing "shoes for women" to "shoes"

Implementing this automation would probably affect 99% of our site if not more, splitting it in 2 segments (one portion of page titles including "women" and the other including "men")
Will doing so create a massively repetitive keyword throughout the site, hurting SEO?
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624 (see "Avoid repeated or boilerplate titles.")

Comment: I feel very confused about this issue too. Best practice is supposed to be including keywords at the beginning of titles but we shouldn't use boilerplate titles. A bit of clarity from Google would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a url structure that includes gender along with h1 page titles which include the gender - this should have the desired effect.